# Can a curve fill a disk?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

How can I prove that there is no $C^1$ - class curve $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ that can fill the unit disk?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, note that $\gamma$ being $C^1$ implies that $\gamma$ is rectifiable. Hence, the Hausdorff dimension of the image of $\gamma$ is $1$ (unless, of course, $\gamma$ is constant). However, the Hausdorff dimension of the unit disk is $2$, by the existence of the Lesbegue measure.

Comment: Note that all we need for this argument is that $|\gamma|$ has bounded variation.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not familliar with Hausdorff dimension. Is there an easier way to prove this?

Comment: I don't think that there is a good proof of this fact that doesn't essentially state: "The image of $\gamma$ has a curve-length, but the curve-length of the unit disk is infinite."

Answer (score 2):

The image of a $C^1$ map $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$ has measure zero. This is Sard's theorem.